# Android navigation drawer baseactivity possible with different items?

Tags: android

I find a lot of tutorials on the Internet on how to implement a navigation drawer for Android Studio.

However, let's say I want to create a navigation drawer for any activity but with different items, is it possible to create some sort of baseactivity so I only need to write the NavDrawerItems and the DrawerItemClickListener ...

Can this BaseActivity be achieved or is it too far fetched?  I searched alot on Google about this, but didn't find any tutorials concerning this particular question I got :(  Most of the baseactivity tutorials I find are for navigation drawer with the same items.

**Edit:**

Code I have for now, but in my opinion it's a bit long to read:

Tutorials I used are:

https://trinitytuts.com/android-navigation-drawer-with-material-design-arrow/ http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/put-image-navigation-drawer/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;

private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mRequestsArray;

Toolbar toolbar;
TextView toolbarTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.context = this;

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mRequestsArray = new String[] { "Catalog", "Account", "Checkout", "Utilities"};
    mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletool);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mRequestsArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            toolbar,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            toolbarTitle.setText(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            toolbarTitle.setText(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setTitle(getTitle());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new CatalogFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AccountFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new CheckoutFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new UtilitiesFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        selectItem(position);

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mRequestsArray[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    toolbarTitle.setText(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Comment: *Can this BaseActivity be achieved or is it too far fetched?* - why it would be far fetched? There's nothing stopping you from putting the drawer layout and code in the base activity and then providing an adapter with different mRequestArray(as an example for your code) in the extending child activities for the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's possible. You can set it when preparing your list data, as the following sample

```
private static void prepareListData(final Context context) {
    final Activity activity = ((Activity) context);
    String activity_name = context.getClass().getSimpleName().replace("Activity", "");

    sListDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    sListDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    // adding header data, except current activity
    String[] mItemHeaders = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array_expandable_header);

    // here...
    for (String item : mItemHeaders) {
        if (!item.toLowerCase().equals(activity_name.toLowerCase())) {
            sListDataHeader.add(item);
        }
    }

    String[] mItemMainChild = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array_expandable_main_child);

    // Child data
    List<String> listChild = Arrays.asList(mItemMainChild);

    // Header, Child data
    for (int i = 0; i < sListDataHeader.size() - 2; i++) {
        sListDataChild.put(sListDataHeader.get(i), new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    sListDataChild.put(sListDataHeader.get(sListDataHeader.size() - 1), listChild);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I recently created a baseactivity to create a navigation drawer where all the other activites get the same items.  But then it occurred to me I can use the keyword 'protected' for some variables, so I can approach the variables 'mRequestsArray' and 'mDrawerLayout' in the extending activity to create other items with their own listener attached to it.

Comment: In my project, NavigationDrawer and its members are in a separate public class (named NavigationDrawerListView), NavigationDrawerActivity (base activity) setups this NavigationDrawer. The other activities (including MainActivity) just need to extend NavigationDrawerActivity.